# How to remove certain characters from lists (Python 2.7)?

Tags: python, string, list, replace, strip

I've got a list where each element is:

```
['a ',' b ',' c ',' d\n ']
```

I want to manipulate it so that each element just becomes:

```
['a','b','c','d']
```

I don't think the spaces matter, but for some reason I can't seem to remove the \n from the end of the 4th element. I've tried converting to string and removing it using:

```
str.split('\n')
```

No error is returned, but it doesn't do anything to the list, it still has the \n at the end.

I've also tried:

```
d.replace('\n','')
```

But this just returns an error.

This is clearly a simple problem but I'm a complete beginner to Python so any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Edit:

It seems I have a list of arrays (I think) so am I right in thinking that list[0], list[1] etc are their own arrays? Does that mean I can use a for loop for i in list to strip \n from each one?

Comment: If you don't want them in the list, why not avoid putting them in, rather than bodging it later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> my_array = ['a ',' b ',' c ',' d\n ']
>>> my_array = [c.strip() for c in my_array]
>>> my_array
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

If you have a list of arrays then you can do something in the lines of:

```
>>> list_of_arrays = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a ', ' b ', ' c ', ' d\n ']]
>>> new_list = [[c.strip() for c in array] for array in list_of_arrays]
>>> new_list
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I have a list of arrays? I think your answer would work, but I would need to do it for every array in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
arr = ['a ',' b ',' c ',' d\n ']

arr = [s.strip() for s in arr]
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple answer is join your list, strip the nextline charcter and split to get a new list:

Newlist = ''.join(myList).strip().split()

Your Newlist is now:

['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']